# Simple Bootstap Form m- Can't quite tidy up buttons/Text alignment

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Continuation of a project I've been working on over the past week. This is for a course so we have to fit it along the lines as the guide (hence using Bootstap in the main).  We'll be adding REACT next so I've had to gear it towards BS4 (I used cdd grid at one stage  - this was a really helpful learning curve, so I've saved that method for future projects) otherwise I'll end up 'off piste' when we move onto the next stage.
It's looking pretty good for me now, but far from perfect.  I've struggled to fit the text centrally in the elements (white text boxes as you'll see on the image) - they're floating to the top. I've tried various align methods/centre to no avail.  The No. 3 Button in the 'Outstanding Tasqs field nudges the border rather than aligned centrally vertically.

Sample code of the section here (I added text-center but it isn't working - also added a .center class wirth margin: auto which didn't work either).

Also (and not sure if this can be altered) when the Complete and Delete buttons 'shrink' in reponsive mode (down to mobile) I can't seem to get these aligned centrally underneath their corresponding text boxes...not a biggy, but I guess it would be helpful to know at this stage.

I've linked a codepen, though it seems to be missing some CSS (like button colours and background?).

Many thanks.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/somapop/pen/bGGwmVR)

[image: Screen Shot of Page]

```
    <div class="row ToDoRow top-buffer">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-center">
            <div class="input">
                <h3>Book Flights</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="btn-toolbar text-center well">
                <div class="col-6 col-md-3 buttonPad">
                    <button type="button" class="btn my-primary my-small-btn btn btn-sm" ">COMPLETE</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class=" col-6 col-md-3 buttonPad">
                    <button type="button" class="btn my-primary2 btn-sm my-small-btn" ">DELETE</button>
                </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a working example of your code? something in jsfiddle for example. make it much easier to see.As its impossible to see with just a bit of HTML.

Comment: Apologies - I thought I'd linked my codepen (and screenshot) but looks like it didn't work - let me edit the message....